# AWS Dynamo Smart Home Schema (Locations/Rooms)

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am trying to build out a scalable smart home infrastructure on AWS using iot core, lambda, and dynamodb along with the serverless framework and subsequent Android/iOS app.

I am implementing locations and rooms in dynamodb. A user can have many locations, and locations can have many rooms. I am used to using Firebase Firestore, so the use of partition keys and sort keys (hash and range?) and the combination to query are a little confusing. I implemented my own hash to use as a primary (partition? hash?) id. Here is the structure I am thinking of:

**Location**

- id
- name
- username

I also added a secondary index on `username`, so that a user could query all of their locations.

**Room**

- id
- name
- locationId

I also added a secondary index on `locationId`, so that a user could query all rooms for a given location

Here is the code in which I create the id's:

```
// need a unique hash for the id
let hash = event.name + event.username + new Date().getTime();

let id = crypto.createHash('md5').update(hash).digest('hex');
let location = {
    id: id,
    name: event.name,
    username: event.username
};
```

And for rooms:

```
// need a unique hash for the id
let hash = event.name + event.locationId + new Date().getTime();
```

Since I'm fairly new to Dynamo/AWS, I'm wondering if this is an acceptable solution. Obviously I would expand on this by adding multiple devices under rooms by associating via the `roomId`. I would also like to be able to share devices, so I'm not quite sure how that would work, as the association for a user is on location - so I assume I would have to share location, room(s), and device(s) (which I think is how Google Home does it)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
The queries that I can think of would be:

- Get Location by Id
- Get all Locations by User
- Get Room by Id
- Get all Rooms by Location

However as the app expands in the future, I would want these queries to be flexible (share location, get shared locations, etc)

Comment: the design of no sql database depends on how you are going to query it please mention in bullet point what are actual queries you are going to use ?

Comment: @varnit I added a few of the queries I could think would be useful in this application

Answer (score 2):

> I would want these queries to be flexible

Then noSQL in general and Dynamo specifically may not be the right choice.

As @varnit alludes to, noSQL DB's are very flexible in what you store, but very inflexible in how you can query that data.

Dynamo for instance can only return a list (Query) if you use a sort key (SK) or if you do a full table scan (not recommended).  Otherwise, it can only return a single record.

I don't understand what a "shared location" would entail.

But with multiple tenets in Dynamo, (each user is only looking at their data) the easy solution would be to use userID as the partition key (PK).

I'd use a composite sort key of location#room

- Get Location by Id --> GetItem(PK = User, SK = location)
- Get all Locations by User --> Query (PK = User)
- Get all rooms by Location --> Query (PK = User, SK starts with Location)

This one is a little trickier...
 - Get Room by Id -->

If you really need to get a room without having the location, then you'd want to have room as stand-a-lone attribute in addition to having it as part of the sort key.  Then you can create a local secondary index over it and query (PK = User, Index SK = Room)

I suspect that finding a room via GetItem(PK = User, SK = location#room) might work for you instead.

Key point, the partition key comparision is **always** equal.  There's no start with, ends with or contains for the partition key comparison.

If you haven't seen them, take a look at the following videos
[AWS re:Invent 2018: Building with AWS Databases: Match Your Workload to the Right Database (DAT301)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwnNbLXN4vA)
[AWS re:Invent 2018: Amazon DynamoDB Deep Dive: Advanced Design Patterns for DynamoDB (DAT401)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k)

Also be sure to read the [SaaS Storage Strategies - Building a Multitenant Storage Model on AWS](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Multi_Tenant_SaaS_Storage_Strategies.pdf) whitepaper.

**EDIT**
"location" and "room" can be whatever makes the most sense to your application.  GUID or a natural key such as "Home".  In a noSQL db, GUIDs are useful when multiple nodes are adding records.  But a natural key is good when that what the application user will have handy.  Since you don't want to have to look up a guid by the natural key.  RDBMS practices don't apply to noSQL DBs.

So yes, I'd use "Home" as the location, meaning the user won't be able to have multiple "Home"s.  But I don't see that as a big deal, I'd use "Home" and "Vacation House" in real life.

**EDIT2**
Dynamo doesn't care if it's a GUID or a natural key.  It internally hashes the whatever value you use for partition key.  All that matters is the number of distinct values. Distinct is distinct, doesn't matter if the value is '0ae4ad25-5551-46a7-8e39-64619645bd58' or 'charles.wilt@mydomain.com'.  If your authorization process returns a GUID, use that.  Otherwise use the username.

Comment: So if I were to use the user as PK and location/room (i'm assuming you mean the name?) as SK, that would mean a user can't have a location/room with the same name? (Not sure why a user would want two locations called 'Home', but this just seems like it could complicate other tables down the road.)

Now that I think about it, maybe you wouldn't need to get a room by id. It was just easier to cache on the mobile app side (just have reference to a single id).

Comment: Looking back at your question, we've not address "events"   ... can you give some examples and how you expect to query that that data?

Comment: From an app perspective the app would have to store either a GUID (currently returned when a user creates an entry) or a "natural" key (such as "Home"). From my understanding and your comments - using a GUID as a partition key is bad because Dynamo divides a table's items into multiple partitions, and distributes the data primarily based upon the partition key value. So using the username for a partition key would be best in this situation. Am I starting to get a hang of it?

Comment: Also the 'event' variable is just the lambda event.

Comment: Ok, I have been testing out various solutions and I'm still coming up with issues. I tried implementing your above suggestion by using a composite sort key of location#room. But what if a user wants to rename a location? Wouldn't they have to update the sort key on the room? I'm really struggling to see how people can actually work with Dynamo :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186148/discussion-between-charles-and-nelson-b-austin).